# ClickOnce: Do I have to sign the ClickOnce manifest and assembly?

Tags: clickonce

I am about to deploy a ClickOnce application for internal use. I will be personally handing the application out to a trusted set of users. I understand that it is possible to sign the ClickOnce manifest, but is there a need to when the user trusts the source?

What are the downsides to not signing the manifest or assembly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to sign the manifest, but there is no need to sign the assembly. You need to sign the manifest so that ClickOnce can uniquely identify the installation (you can install the application twice by signing the application with two different keys).

If you are only doing an internal application, your certificate can just be a certificate you create, it does not have to be trusted.

The only benefit of signing any assemblies would be that ClickOnce can optimize the download and store strongly signed assemblies outside of your applications isolated storage and share the assembly across multiple applications. For example, if you have two applications that both use the same version of [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) then ClickOnce will only download the assemblies once.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Presumably the option to 'create test certificate' would be the choice to use to create my own?

Comment: That should surfice. One thing to bear in mind if you are not using .net 4.0 is that if you every change the certificate you will not be able to upgrade existing installations, ClickOnce will see it as a new installation.

Comment: That's not strictly true. You can change the certificate with impunity if you are using .NET 3.5 or .NET 2.0 w/SP-1, and are using automatic updates.

The other reason to sign the deployment is that the signing is checked when updates are done and at install time, and if it's not right, it can tell the files have been messed with. So it won't install an update that has been hijacked or replaced by someone (like with malware).

Comment: Also, ClickOnce caches all of the assemblies in a deployment, and doesn't download them again if they don't change. Obviously if you are building the dll for the publish, it will change, but if you have any 3rd party dll's or dll's that you have created in another solution and added to the project, they would only be downloaded the first time. After that, they would be used from the local cache.

Comment: Use makecert.exe to create a certificate with an expiration date far out into the future to avoid having automatic update problems. The test certificate VS generates is only good for one year.